# view column of other model in a view of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models named: `um_org_data.rb`

```
class UmOrgDatum < ActiveRecord::Base


  attr_accessible :org_description, :org_name, :webdomain, :addresses, :addresses_attributes

  has_many :addresses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

and `addresses.rb`

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :offc_addr

  belongs_to :um_org_datum

end
```

in my controller i use join.. as following in the code `um_org_data.rb`

```
class UmOrgDataController < ApplicationController
  # GET /um_org_data
  # GET /um_org_data.json
  def index
     @um_org_data = UmOrgDatum.joins(:addresses)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @um_org_data }
    end
  end
```

now in my view i want to show the data of offc_addr column from `addresses.rb` in the view of `um_org_data.html.erb` in which controller i use join.. the code of my view is following:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
                    <div class="span3 pull-right">
                      <div class="well">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Sample text</p>
                      </div> 
                    </div> 

    <div class="span9">
            <h2> List of Organization Details</h2>
            <%= b_search_bar(um_org_data_path).html_safe %><br/><br/>




                    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Organization Name</th>
                        <th>Organization Description</th>
                        <th>Web Domain</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                      </tr>

                      <% @um_org_data.each do |um_org_data| %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= um_org_data.org_name %></td>
                            <td><%= um_org_data.org_description%></td>
                            <td><%= um_org_data.webdomain%></td>
                            <td><%= um_org_datum.addresses.offc_addr%></td>
                            <td>
                              <%= link_to "<i class='icon-eye-open'></i>".html_safe, um_org_data,"data-original-title" => "View Details", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none' %>

                              <%= link_to "<i class= 'icon-edit'></i>".html_safe, edit_um_org_datum_path(um_org_data), "data-original-title" => "Edit", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none'%>

                              <%= link_to "<i class= 'icon-trash'></i>".html_safe, um_org_data, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, "data-original-title" => "Delete", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none' %>   
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                      <%end%>
                    </table>
        <div><a class="btn" href="/um_org_data/new" style="text-color:black">Add Organization</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tell me how to show the column of other table in that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want each org to have multiple addresses? If yes, then do

```
<td><%= um_org_datum.addresses.pluck(:offc_addr).join(', ') %></td>
```

This will give you a column of addresses in a comma-separated list. If each org should only have one address, use `has_one :address` and in your view,

```
<td><%= um_org_datum.address.offc_addr %></td>
```

The problem you're currently having is that you are treating `um_org_datum.addresses` like a single model instance, when in fact it is an array of addresses.

Comment: can you tell me how can i use condition for join that i use in my controller